# How to resolve the following error in struts 2. I guess I should type cast the date format to string? How to do it?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

```
public class SimpleSorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] data = {4,7,2,5,3};
        bubbleSort(data);

        //selectionSort(data);
        //insertionSort(data);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] data) {
        for(int out=data.length-1; out>=1; out--) {
            for(int in=0; in < out; in++) {
                if(data[in]>data[in+1]) {
                    swap(data, in, in+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me. I am having a lot of doubts in this part of code. Should I send the whole array or is it possible to sort the array using the indices alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `DateFormat` in the top(**just before `iterate` tag is also fine**) as :

```
//use the date format patter as desired 
<% java.text.DateFormat formatter= new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy)");%>
```

**Get the Date String as:**

```
 formatter.format(Parent_Engagement_Name);
```

Updated section int your code will look like:

```
 <s:iterator value="parentEngagementOfList">
        <s:property value="Parent_Engagement_Name"/>
        <s:set name="myenv" value="%{Parent_Engagement_Name}"/>
        <s:set name="num" value="%{formatter.format(Parent_Engagement_Date)}"/>
           <li><a href=""><s:property value="%{myenv}"/></a></li>
           <li><a href=""><s:date value="%{num}"/></a></li>
           <p>This is inside iterator </p>


</s:iterator>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. May I know like in which files of mine should I do the changes. Please PLease say me that too.

Comment: The same JSP page where you have the `iterate` tag. I updated my answer with little additional details to help you better. Please let me know, if still any questions.

Comment: Thanks, It was really helpful. Similarly could you guide me for type casting int to string in jsp.

Comment: Two ways. Either directly write like `String.valueOf(intValue)` or just do `""+intValue` i.e. `Blank String` concatenated with your `int value`.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I need it for String to int conversion in JSP. I have been trying like this. Yet to compile. Will it work. <s:set name="id"  value="%{Integer.parseInt(ParentEngagementId)}"/> or should I add anything anywhere.

Comment: It should work, but if you are just setting the value, do you really need to convert?

Comment: It worked. Thanks ji. If I am not converting I am getting error. I am actually gonna use the value soon

Comment: Good to know that it worked. If you have other questions, feel free to ask. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`date` tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/date.html):

```
<s:date name="parentEngagementDetials.Parent_Engagement_Date" format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

Comment: Thanks for helping and replying. Tried as you have given, its not coming. Should I add value tag in the snippet you have given above. Any suggestions.

Comment: I tried this and its working. U rock brother. Thank you very mcuh . <li><a href=""><s:property value="%{myenv}"/><s:date name="%{num}" format="dd/MM/yyyy"  /></a></li>

Comment: Glad to be of help - if this answered your question, then I'd appreciate you marking my answer as correct by clicking on the "tick" icon.